# unable to use $match operator for mongodb/mongoose aggregation with ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Relatively Simple Scenario:

I have this `Voucher` object which has a `user` property (of type `ObjectId`). I want to get the sum of all voucher values for a single user. Here is my current strategy, which returns an empty array:

```
Voucher.aggregate [
    { $match : { user : new ObjectId(user_id), expires : { $gt : new Date() } } }
    { $group : { _id : null, sum : { $sum : '$value' } } }
], (err, result)->

    console.log err
    console.log result
```

Removing the match for the `user` id, and leaving the `expires` field will return results. So the question becomes what is wrong with the match on `user`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; `$match` works for me with an `ObjectId` in a plain mongo shell. I don't know what the `dc` in your code block is. Is that a Mongoose thing?

Comment: To be specific, here's what I did in the mongo shell: In my test database, I did `db.tmp.save({foo: ObjectId()})`. Then after finding its ID with a `findOne`, I did `db.users.aggregate({$match:{foo:ObjectId("5180956a55064fce4d42f02d")}})` and the document was returned in the results. Can you try this, and then try reducing your question to a minimum example of the issue? I'm using Mongo 2.4.3, by he way.

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the help. The dc is a context object with some helpers (like Object Id). So please ignore that. I reduced the aggregate to `{ $match : { user : new ObjectId(user_id) } }` and am still receiving a result of `[]`.

Comment: Running the same aggregation in mongo shell is working.

Comment: Thanks for the help Doug, ultimately led me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Turns out the casting of the ObjectId seemed to be the issue. It was being cast using the Schema type Object Id `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` when it needed to be just a pure ObjectId `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`.

Comment: +1.  I just got bit by this.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: thanks a bunch.. at least there's still hair left in my head :( you saved me xD

Answer (score 21):

When using the find method or findById the query can be only:

```
var query = {
    $or: [
        {'_sender':req.body._id},
        {'_recipient':req.body._id}
    ]
};
```

When using aggregate the query need a cast

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var query = {
    $or: [
        {'_sender':new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(decoded._id)},
        {'_recipient':new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(decoded._id)}
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var aggregate  = [
{
                $match: {
                    'lenderId': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user),
                    '_disbursed': true
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind:'$emi'
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    'emi._settled': false,
                }
            }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

use toString() method.

{ $match : { user : user_id.toString() , expires : { $gt : new Date() } } }