# MongoDB-Mongoose Aggregation with geoNear and query parameter, using _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get that code working.
I have to select some people based on distance, from an array of _ids that I already have.

I'm trying to do:

```
Volunteer.aggregate(
    [
      {
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [7.6852228, 45.0714124]
            },
            "distanceField": "distance",
            "maxDistance": 1000,
            "spherical": true,
            "query": { _id: "5597f359bc2683902b3ba7b2" }
            /*"query": { 
                "_id": { "$in" : ["5597f359bc2683902b3ba7b2"] }
            }*/
          }
      }, {
          "$sort": {
          "distance": -1
          }
      } // Sort nearest first
    ],
      function(err, docs) {
        if(err){
          res.jsonFail(err);
        }else{
          res.jsonSuccess(docs);
        }
      }
  );
```

If I pass, as field of the query parameter, an _id, I get zero result.

If I comment it out, or search by another field (firstname for example), it show me the results.

Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to use $match operator for mongodb/mongoose aggregation with ObjectId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310598/unable-to-use-match-operator-for-mongodb-mongoose-aggregation-with-objectid)