# MongoDB, Aggregate $match not working on ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that is:

```
var photoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,     // Unique ID identifying this photo
    file_name: String,
    date_time: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    user_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // The user id of the user who created the photo.
    comments: [commentSchema] // Comment objects representing the comments made on this photo.
});

var Photo = mongoose.model('Photo', photoSchema);
```

I am trying to find the photo from a specific user with most number of comments. Here is what I have done:

```
Photo.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                id: 1,
                file_name: 1,
                date_time: 1,
                user_id: 1,
                comments: 1,
                length: {$size: "$comments"}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                user_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(request.params.id)
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: { length: -1 }
        }
        ], function (err, info2){
            if (err) {
                    // Query returned an error.
                    console.error('Doing /user/usage/:id error:', err);
                    response.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(err));
                    return;
            }
            console.log(info2);
            finalOutput.most_commented = info2[0];
            response.end(JSON.stringify(finalOutput));
        });
```

I only get an empty array [] in the console.log, I know the $match is not working because if I remove $match clause, it gives me the photo with max comments across the entire table. I want to filter and get the photo which belong to 1 specific user, based on their user_id.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
I have tried:
1. $match: {user_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(request.params.id)}
2. $match: {user_id: request.params.id}
3. $match: {"user_id": request.params.id}

Comment: Can you take a look at this  ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310598/unable-to-use-match-operator-for-mongodb-mongoose-aggregation-with-objectid

Comment: ^^ Thanks!     Turns out the casting of the ObjectId seemed to be the issue. It was being cast using the Schema type Object Id mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId when it needed to be just a pure ObjectId mongoose.Types.ObjectId. (Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16312935/5382718)

Comment: I spent hours last night on this, so silly! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to use $match operator for mongodb/mongoose aggregation with ObjectId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310598/unable-to-use-match-operator-for-mongodb-mongoose-aggregation-with-objectid)

Comment: @BNKS it's looks like very slimier, almost duplicate, can you please self care of it to make site clean :)

Answer (score 6):

> **First Step**

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId
```

> **Second Step**

```
{ $match : { _id: ObjectId("606c74d5f9e3f30f8caa3451")} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Id variable would be constructed of "strings", and not ObjectId values. Mongoose "autocasts" string values for ObjectId into their correct type in regular queries but not in aggregation. More details - https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399

That's why you need to do the casting in the code itself.

```
{ $match : { _id: mongoose.Types("606c74d5f9e3f30f8caa3451")} }
```

(Don't forget to import mongoose)