# How to get size of array embedded array mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a category collection and I want to get category by id with some options. This is collection's structure in database.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d67296bf35b984e74486924",
    "name": "Dinrk",
    "images": [],
    "recipes": [
      {
        "name": "Coffee",
        "time": 20,
        "img": "https://google.com/image-example.jpg",
        "des": "This is description",
        "serving": 2,
        "components": [
          {
            "name": "Dink 1",
            "quantity": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Dink 2",
            "quantity": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Dink 2",
            "quantity": "1"
          }
        ],
        "cook_steps": [
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          },
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Coffee",
        "time": 20,
        "img": "https://google.com/image-example.jpg",
        "des": "This is description",
        "serving": 2,
        "components": [
          {
            "name": "Dink 1",
            "quantity": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Dink 2",
            "quantity": "1"
          }
        ],
        "cook_steps": [
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          },
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5d67296bf35b984e74486435555",
    "name": "Cake",
    "images": [],
    "recipes": [
      {
        "name": "Cake",
        "time": 20,
        "img": "https://google.com/image-example.jpg",
        "des": "This is description",
        "serving": 2,
        "components": [
          {
            "name": "Cake 1",
            "quantity": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Cake 2",
            "quantity": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Cake 2",
            "quantity": "1"
          }
        ],
        "cook_steps": [
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          },
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Coffee",
        "time": 20,
        "img": "https://google.com/image-example.jpg",
        "des": "This is description",
        "serving": 2,
        "components": [
          {
            "name": "Cake 1",
            "quantity": "1"
          }
        ],
        "cook_steps": [
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          },
          {
            "des": "This is description",
            "pictures": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my code to try categoryId = "5d67296bf35b984e74486924"

```js
Category.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {'_id': categoryId}
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$recipes'
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    'total_components': {'$size': '$recipes.components'},
                    'total_cook_steps': {'$size': '$recipes.cook_steps'}
                }
            }
        ]).then(function(data) {

}, function(err) {

})
```

And expected result is

```
{
    "_id": "5d67296bf35b984e74486924",
    "name": "Dinrk",
    "images": [],
    "recipes": [
      {
        "name": "Coffee",
        "time": 20,
        "img": "https://google.com/image-example.jpg",
        "des": "This is description",
        "serving": 2,
        "total_components": 3,
        "total_cook_steps": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Coffee",
        "time": 20,
        "img": "https://google.com/image-example.jpg",
        "des": "This is description",
        "serving": 2,
        "total_components": 2,
        "total_cook_steps": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

But when I run above my code, result is [].

If you understand my problem, please help me. I have search a lot, but not found solution. So I want to ask everyone. Thankyou so much.

Comment: Type of the `categoryId` must be ObjectId not string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310598/unable-to-use-match-operator-for-mongodb-mongoose-aggregation-with-objectid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not giving you the desired result since Mongoose [does not auto-cast the 24 char hex string to ObjectId in its aggregate pipeline](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399) since `$project` and `$group` can change the schema in surprising ways that it becomes hard to infer what should be an `ObjectId`.

You need to manually convert the `categoryId` 
string to `ObjectId` using the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` method.

Compute the new fields within a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator instead of [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as this allows you an aggregate operation with fewer pipeline steps

```
Category.aggregate([
    { '$match': { '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(categoryId) } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'recipes': {
            '$map': {
                'input': '$recipes',
                'in': {
                    'name': '$$this.name',
                    'time': '$$this.time',
                    'img': '$$this.img',
                    'des': '$$this.des',
                    'serving': '$$this.serving',
                    'total_components': { '$size': '$$this.components' },
                    'total_cook_steps': { '$size': '$$this.cook_steps' }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
]).then(function(data) {

}, function(err) {

})
```

Comment: Awesome, it's worked. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it!