# Does geoNear aggregation not work when the query field is the objectId?

Tags: mongodb

My geonear code work except when I put query: {id: req.params.id}. It works for any other filter obj I put.

Does anyone know how to query for a certain document using the objectId while using geoNear?

I presently have what's below. Is there also any way to do the matching on the document first i.e {$match: {id: req.params.id}. I tried doing this but since $geoNear has to be the first step in the pipeline it didn't work out.

```
const distances = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [lng, lat],
          },
          //   maxDistance: 13.3333 * 1000,
          spherical: true,
          distanceField: "distance",
          distanceMultiplier: 0.001,
          query: { _id: req.params.id },
        },
      },
      { $project: { id: 1, distance: 1 } },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[unable to use $match operator for mongodb/mongoose aggregation with ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310598/unable-to-use-match-operator-for-mongodb-mongoose-aggregation-with-objectid) ^ This fixed it sorry!